# Damp/Wet Corners with Mold in House

Tags: water, mold, moisture

In the outer corners along the external walls of our house, and inside closets on external walls we are experiencing water and moisture gathering on the flooring and there is mold appearing on the flooring and baseboards.

We're not sure what steps we could take to remedy this, or what type of person we could call to assess the issues.

We live in a 1300sqft ranch-style house on slab foundation, it is about 31 years old. We purchased this house about 10 months ago. Our house is heated primarily with a Mini-Split Heat Pump (Heat/AC) and Baseboards. We also have a Wood Stove when it gets too cold.

Both larger heat sources (Mini-Split and Wood Stove) are on the opposite ends of our Bedroom and Office, but we also notice moisture build up in the corners near them as well so we don't believe that in itself is the issue.

The attic has 6 inches of insulation, if that would make a difference.

This picture is from our office.

[image]

This is from our bedroom.

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I don't see any moisture evidence in these pictures; would you  provide some details, either in text or other pictures?

Comment: @DanielGriscom The second picture is kind of hard to see for sure. The first picture though has the best shot of water and moisture build up on the floor we've been able to get. The water/moisture/condensation starts to reappear within a few hours of being dried up.

Comment: Ah; I misinterpreted the glints on the drops as dust specs. What's the humidity level in the house? You'll likely need to a) reduce humidity, and b) block incoming cold drafts.\